# Sorting emissions in Rx using sorted() or toSortedList() not working

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I'm trying to sort the emissions of an `Observable` using either `sorted()` or `toSortedList()`.

Here's my code:

```
bookshelfUseCase.addedBooks(uid, BookshelfRepositoryContract.READ_LIST)
            .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
            .doOnNext { Log.d("RLP1", it.toString()) }
            .toSortedList { first, second -> first.timestamp.compareTo(second.timestamp) }
            .toObservable()
            .doOnNext { Log.d("RLP2", it.toString()) }
            .subscribe { getView().showBooks(it) }
```

Here, I'm comparing the timestamp of each `Book` to get a sorted list for showing it to the user.

### What's the problem?

The `Observable` or `Single` returned by `sorted()` or `toSortedList()` doesn't emit anything. Just blank. Zero emissions.

Here's the output of log printed by the `doOnNext()` before and after `toSortedList()` is called:

```
02-18 01:54:27.743 25032-25032/com.bookwritten D/RLP1: Book(id=368593, title=The 4-Hour Workweek, year=2007, author=Author(id=210456, name=Timothy Ferriss), rating=3.85, coverImageUrl=https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png, coverImageUrlSmall=https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png, checkInTime=0, timestamp=1518895501664)
02-18 01:54:27.743 25032-25032/com.bookwritten D/RLP1: Book(id=12605157, title=The $100 Startup: Reinvent the Way You Make a Living, Do What You Love, and Create a New Future, year=2012, author=Author(id=3367145, name=Chris Guillebeau), rating=3.85, coverImageUrl=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1345666854m/12605157.jpg, coverImageUrlSmall=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1345666854s/12605157.jpg, checkInTime=0, timestamp=0)
02-18 01:54:27.743 25032-25032/com.bookwritten D/RLP1: Book(id=13497818, title=The Casual Vacancy, year=2012, author=Author(id=1077326, name=J.K. Rowling), rating=3.28, coverImageUrl=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1509893913m/13497818.jpg, coverImageUrlSmall=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1509893913s/13497818.jpg, checkInTime=0, timestamp=0)
02-18 01:54:27.743 25032-25032/com.bookwritten D/RLP1: Book(id=29095176, title=Lyrebird, year=2016, author=Author(id=7116, name=Cecelia Ahern), rating=3.76, coverImageUrl=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1465023152m/29095176.jpg, coverImageUrlSmall=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1465023152s/29095176.jpg, checkInTime=0, timestamp=0)
02-18 01:54:27.743 25032-25032/com.bookwritten D/RLP1: Book(id=31823677, title=Tools of Titans: The Tactics, Routines, and Habits of Billionaires, Icons, and World-Class Performers, year=2016, author=Author(id=210456, name=Timothy Ferriss), rating=4.25, coverImageUrl=https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png, coverImageUrlSmall=https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png, checkInTime=0, timestamp=0)
02-18 01:54:27.743 25032-25032/com.bookwritten D/RLP1: Book(id=36204090, title=Crushing It!: How Great Entrepreneurs Build Their Business and Influence—and How You Can, Too, year=0, author=Author(id=1371305, name=Gary Vaynerchuk), rating=4.58, coverImageUrl=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1514065832m/36204090.jpg, coverImageUrlSmall=https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1514065832s/36204090.jpg, checkInTime=0, timestamp=0)
```

As you can see, no logs are being printed after the `toSortedList()` has been called in the chain.

What could I be missing here?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These operators require finite sequences. Is `.addedBooks` finite?

Comment: Yup seems like that was the problem. It was connected to a Firebase Realtime DB which is technically infinite. I ended up sorting the list within `subscribe{}` and it works now. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I made the mistake of applying `sorted()` on an infinite `Observable`, as pointed out by @akarnokd.

The `Observable` in question is infinite because it's connected to a **Firebase Realtime DB**.

Therefore, my sorting problem was easily solved by sorting the values on `subscribe{}` rather than applying the function within the chain. The code goes like this:

```
bookshelfUseCase.addedBooks(uid, BookshelfRepositoryContract.MY_BOOKS)
            .subscribe { getView().showBooks(it.sortedWith(compareByDescending { it.timestamp })) }
```

Hope this saves someone's time.